# How to run java class in JAR file in maven target directory?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, izpack, exec-maven-plugin

I would like to run my Izpack installer after maven build, but I am getting following output after executing "mvn test":

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building RS IzPack installer
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] [resources:copy-resources {execution: copy-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 109 resources
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Preparing exec:java
[WARNING] Removing: java from forked lifecycle, to prevent recursive invocation.
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] [resources:copy-resources {execution: copy-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 109 resources
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] [exec:java {execution: default}]
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.izforge.izpack.installer.Installer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.izforge.izpack.installer.Installer
```

Looks like I have to somehow put generated jar file into classpath, any ideas?

Excerpt from my pom.xml :

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>java</goal> <!-- "exec" also possible -->
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.izforge.izpack.installer.Installer</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-console</argument>
            <!-- <argument>arg1</argument> -->
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 21:16:01+0200)
Java version: 1.6.0_20
Java home: C:\Java\jdk16\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp" version: "5.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked inside of jar ? It can be that maven didn't included needed classes into jar.

Comment: Yes, I have looked in my target\Installer-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standard.jar and class com.izforge.izpack.installer.Installer is inside the jar. I have no problem to execute it from cmd line by running "java -jar Installer-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standard.jar". Just from maven it is problem to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should define the classpath for the `java` command using `-classpath`. You need to construct a classpath that will contain Your main class `com.izforge.izpack.installer.Installer` and all it's dependencies. It can be in a jar, or a class folder or multiple jars. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) on how to define a classpath for java call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that to define a dependency for that execution:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>test</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>java</goal> <!-- "exec" also possible -->
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <mainClass>com.izforge.izpack.installer.Installer</mainClass>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-console</argument>
        <!-- <argument>arg1</argument> -->
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>izpack-standalone-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But there is also a [Maven plugin for izpack](http://izpack.codehaus.org/izpack-maven-plugin/usage.html).